# Cómo comparar, detectar y reemplazar registros en función de un vector maestro?

Tags: python, pandas, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un DF mas menos con la siguiente lógica (es mas extenso, es solo ilustrativo)

```
df1 <- data.frame(CALLES = c("RUPERTO MORENO", "ABANDERADO RUPERTO MONTERO", "LINCON", "AIDA", "ACONCAGA", "ABRAHAM LINCOL"),
                  MAESTRO_CALLES = c("ABANDERADO RUPERTO MONTERO", "ABRAHAM LINCOLN", "ACONCAGUA", "AIDA")
```

Entonces, el objetivo es comparar la columna CALLES, con la columna MAESTRO_CALLES.  Detectar cuando la CALLE sea "igual" o "similar" dentro del MAESTRO_CALLE, detectar y reemplazar por la que corresponda. Saludos, y gracias

Comment: Cuál sería el criterio para "similar"? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Ejemplo de "Similar":  RUPERTO MORENO versus ABANDERADO RUPERTO MORENO     ó bien    LINCON versus ABRAHAM LINCOLN

Comment: Buen día, eso no es lo que está preguntando Alfabravo, lo que quiere decir es, ¿En base a qué criterio RUPERTO MORENO es "similar" a ABANDERADO RUPERTO MORENO? Si existiera otra entrada, por ejemplo RUPERTO RUBIO, ¿Sería identificado como similar con RUPERTO MORENO? ¿La similitud es en base a la cantidad de caracteres, caracteres que sean iguales, o cómo lo harías?

Comment: Buen día, disculpe efectivamente no me expresé correctamente. El criterio básico de "similar", es que los caracteres de cada registro [i] de CALLES, estén contenidos en algún registro [j] de MAESTRO_CALLES. Esta última, sirve como base maestra, con ID única.  Entonces, en el ejemplo de RUPERTO MORENO, efectivamente sus caracteres, o parte de ellos, están contenidos en un registro del maestro con ID única, en este caso ABANDERADO RUPERTO MORENO, así como también LINCON, está contenido en ABRAHAM LINCOLN.  Muchas gracias

Comment: Pero si únicamente se comparan los caracteres entonces LINCON y CONLIN cumplirían con la similitud. Yo creo que lo más fácil sería que hicieras un diccionario con las palabras que consideras "similares" y utilizarlo en tu `dataframe`. Por ejemplo {'RUPERTO MORENO': 'ABANDERADO RUPERTO MORENO'}